# TypeError: 'float' object is not

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python, I am reading a file and want to extract multiple different values for "X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.7002" I want to add all the different confidence values.

```
xfile = open('/Users/Documents/python/mbox-short.txt')
for line in xfile:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        continue
    xf = (line.rstrip())
    ## Start Counting Lines
    count = 0 
    for numlines in xf:
        count = count + 1
    ## total count of lines with value <<<< code works up to this point
    values = float(line[20:])
    print(values)
    for n in values:
        print(n)
```

I get error mentioned below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users//Documents/python/chapter7.py", line 14, in <module>
    for n in values:
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Please edit your code to make it more readable.

Comment: Type of `values` is `float` and hence you cannot iterate. Iterate `line[20:]` and then inside the loop, you convert `n` to `float`. @Rupang

Comment: but when I do the following ```    values = xf[20:]
    for num in values :
        print(num) .
7
5
5
6
0 instead of 0.75560

Comment: As a side note, `count = 0; for numlines in xf: count = count + 1` is wrong. It does not do what you think it does. Consider learning elementary Python operations before writing a long program.

Answer (score 0):

You can't iterate over a number(float, int, complex). First you need to transform the number to string.

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop requires a `sequence`  to iter over, eg: A string, a list, tuple, etc. A Float is not a sequence it's a value, basically a number. You can't iter over a value. 
I guess what you are trying to do is convert all elements in `line[20:]` to float and print them one by one. 
One solution would be to Iter over the string and then convert the values to float then print them.

```
values = line[20:]
print(values)
for n in values:
    float_value = float(n)
    print(float_value)
```

This will only work you can convert the said `values` to float i.e. they are either numbers or in this case numeric strings e.g. '1', '2', "Infinity", '1E6', etc. See more on float data type [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float)

Edit: Read in your comment which came after I was done writing that you want to print the value like `0.75560...`. In this case, you don't need the loop at all. Just typecast the value and print it

```py
values = float(line[20:])
print(value)
```

In the method, I wrote about earlier, the for loop takes each value one by one, so if your string is something like '123' and if you do

```py
for n in '123':
    print(n)
```

Your output would be somthing like:

```sh
>> '1'
>> '2'
>> '3'
```